# how to use fast url filters in StormCrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I came across fast url filters. it gives several options like applying filters to specific domain.could someone tel more details about usage of it and how to configure it in url filters.json?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter can be configured in *urlfilters.json* like any other filter i.e.

```
 {
  "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.FastURLFilter",
  "name": "FastURLFilter",
  "params": {
    "file": "fast.urlfilter.json"
  }
}
```

The file parameter is optional and takes the value given above by default.

See [JAVADOC](http://stormcrawler.net/docs/api/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/filtering/regex/FastURLFilter.html), [BLOG](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.com/2018/06/whats-new-in-stormcrawler-110.html) and [WIKI](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/URLFilters) for details.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. that one works fine.but i have another doubt..i am crawling many websites and i have to apply filters separately for each domain under each host ..how can i do it?

Comment: you mean each host under each domain? a) you can specify at the domain level only b) you can just define patterns using the GLOBAL scope. This filter is called fast because if there are rules specifically for a given domain, it will apply these first instead of going through all the rules in order as done with the RegexURLFilter

Comment: i am crawling two websites..each website has a domain "/help/" in it. i have to crawl the "help" domain of one website and ignore the "help" domain of the other.Does storm crawler provide a way for it?

Comment: [
     {
         "scope": "domain:helpdomain.net",
         "patterns": [
             "AllowPath /help/",
             "DenyPath .+"
         ]
     },
     {
         "scope": "domain:helplessdomain.net",
         "patterns": [
             "DenyPath /help/"
         ]
     }
 ]